# How to add a product with two line items

Tags: magento2, cart, addtocart, shopping-cart

```
I want to add a product with two line items.
Say for example if i add Product A with qty of 4.
I need to split cart into two line items.
3 qty as one line item and 1 is in another.
```

How Can I achieve this?

> I have overridden Checkout/Controller/Cart/Add.php

and here is my sample code.

```
foreach ([3,1] as $qty) {
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $_control = $objectManager->create('\Vendor\Module\Observer\Custom');
    $additionalOptions = [];
    if($value == 1){
        $additionalOptions[] = array(
            'label' => 'Discount',
            'value' => 'No'
        );
    }else{
        $additionalOptions[] = array(
            'label' => 'Discount',
            'value' => 'Yes'
        );
    }
    $product->addCustomOption('additional_options',$_control->unserializeCustomOption($additionalOptions));
    $v_params = array(
        'product' => $product->getId(),
        'qty' => $qty,
        'price' => ($qty == 3 ? 76 : 86)
    );
    $this->cart->addProduct($product, $v_params);
}
```

Request which is coming to Quote model is correct only.

```
{"product":"727","qty":3,"price":76}
{"product":"727","qty":1,"price":86}
```

But in the cart its not correct.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check `addProduct` method in class `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote`

Comment: @Anshu Mishra Yeah, Seen.! Magento is restricting to create new item with same product.

Comment: @SainadhMannem I've tried the above way, but it's not working in Magento 2 Vennila setup itself. can you able to achieve using above code in your end?
I wanna the above scenario need to work in config product. Do you have any idea pls share your answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/357461/magento-2-selected-quantity-to-different-line-of-item

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this via `beforeAddProduct` plugin of `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote` where you can assign `addCustomOption` to `$product->addCustomOption('additional_options', $additionalInfo);` where `$additionalInfo` is array like below

```
$additionalInfo[] = [
 'label' => 'Label you want to show',
 'value' => 'Value you want to show'
];
```

on product add time check qty is greater than 3. then you can create new product with custom option so it will work as you want.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply! I have updated my question with my sample code what i have tried so far. Please check once and let me know.